# NSFileManager in document folder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsfilemanager

i am trying to zip a file into a subfolder in my iphone app.

```
 NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *dir = [path objectAtIndex:0];

             NSString *storeunzipfiles = [dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/MyFolder"]; 
 if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:storeunzipfiles])
   [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:storeunzipfiles attributes:nil]; //Create folder
```

ok now i created the folder. What i want to do is to del all the files in the folder before i unzip my file. but i am not getting it.

```
        NSFileManager *filemgr;


           filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

           [filemgr removeItemAtPath: @"/MyFolder" handler: nil];

   // warning: 'NSFileManager' may not respond to '-removeItemAtPath:handler:'

      }     

      }
```

lastly, unzip to subfolder.

```
   if ([zip UnzipFileTo:storeunzipfiles overWrite:YES]) {...
```

ok i got a warning msg...

whats the method to load the files in the subfolder? is this right?

```
NSString *docpath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/MyFolder/Data.plist"];     ?
```

thks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is no `-removeItemAtPath:handler:` method. You want `-removeItemAtPath:error:` instead.

Answer (score 0):

No,

You can use method

```
- (NSArray *)contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error
```

this will return a NSarray object that contains Name of File contains in given folder.
after that u can remove easily. example

```
NSarray *array=[filemanager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"/MyFolder" error:nil];
for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
{
    [filemanager removeItemAtPath:[@"/MyFolder" stringByAppendingPathComponent:[array objectAtIndex:i]] error:nil];
}
```

so folder will be empty